# How to cite an online dictionary entry in BibTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I would like to cite entries from Merriam Webster online dictionary and the Oxford Dictionary online. Neither offers a BiBTeX format. The citation that MW suggests looks like this:

> Merriam-Webster. (n.d.). Abulia. In Merriam-Webster.com dictionary.
> Retrieved July 8, 2020, from
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia

The OED suggests this format (in Chicago style)

> "akrasia, n.". OED Online. June 2020. Oxford University Press.
> https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia (accessed
> July 08, 2020).

How can I enter these into a BiBTeX file and cite them in my work? Or, should I switch to BiBLaTeX and, if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The best input™ will depend the output you expect and the bibliography style you use.** While there is broad agreement in most available BibTeX styles about commonly cited types like `@article`, `@book`, `@incollection`, ... less common types (at the time BibTeX was written) – like online sources – or types not that often cited in STEM fields – like dictionary entries – are far less uniformly supported.

Most styles probably will not have a specific type for (online) dictionary entries. The following types would be obvious choices

- **`@inreference`**. This is a `biblatex` type and I couldn't find any BibTeX style on my machine that supports it. In theory it would be a perfect fit, since `@inreference` is specifically intended to be used for entries in reference works like dictionaries. The `biblatex` standard styles treat `@inreference` pretty much like `@incollection`.

  In `biblatex` you could use

  ```
  @inreference{mw:abulia,
    author    = {Merriam-Webster},
    title     = {Abulia},
    booktitle = {Merriam-Webster.com dictionary},
    url       = {https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia},
    urldate   = {2020-07-08},
  }
  @inreference{oed:akrasia,
    title     = {akrasia, n.},
    booktitle = {OED Online},
    date      = {2020-06},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    url       = {https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia},
    urldate   = {2020-07-08},
  }
  ```
- **`@incollection`**. Most BibTeX styles will support this type. Semantically it is quite a good fit (as a generalisation of `@inreference`). The downside is that some styles may not expect a URL for types like this.

  Slightly adapting the previous example (`date` -> `year`+`month`) we get

  ```
  @incollection{mw:abulia,
    author    = {Merriam-Webster},
    title     = {Abulia},
    booktitle = {Merriam-Webster.com dictionary},
    url       = {https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia},
    urldate   = {2020-07-08},
  }
  @incollection{oed:akrasia,
    title     = {akrasia, n.},
    booktitle = {OED Online},
    year      = {2020},
    month     = jun,
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    url       = {https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia},
    urldate   = {2020-07-08},
  }
  ```

  Note that most BibTeX styles don't support `urldate` and some even don't support `url`, so you may have to work around that with for example `howpublished` and `note` (though some BibTeX styles support a `url` field and a field like `lastchecked`; check out the documentation, experiment a bit or look at the `.bst` source directly to figure out what works).
- **`@online`**. Many newer styles support a type like `@online` or `@electronic`. Often the type does not have fields like `booktitle` where you could put the dictionary name or `publisher`, so some creativity might be needed.
- **`@misc`**. The last resort, but it should be available in all styles. Again, there generally isn't a lot of field structure here for `booktitle`/the dictionary name, so you have to cook up something that looks nice by (ab)using other fields.

One problem with dictionary entries is that they usually have no identifiable author, so the first question is whether or not you want to put the dictionary name as `author` or if you want to leave the `author` field empty. Many styles have no problem with missing `author` fields, but in some setups (`natbib` with `authoryear` option) a missing `author` could be an issue.

Another question is where you put the dictionary name if you use a generic type like `@online` or `@misc`, which generally only supports one type of title.

Just as one data point, here is what the standard `biblatex` style `authoryear` produces with `@inreference`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{mw:abulia,
  author    = {Merriam-Webster},
  title     = {Abulia},
  booktitle = {Merriam-Webster.com dictionary},
  url       = {https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia},
  urldate   = {2020-07-08},
}
@inreference{oed:akrasia,
  title     = {akrasia, n.},
  booktitle = {OED Online},
  date      = {2020-06},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  url       = {https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia},
  urldate   = {2020-07-08},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{mw:abulia,oed:akrasia}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Merriam-Webster 2020; akrasia, n. 2020)//akrasia, n. (June 2020). In: OED Online. Oxford University Press. url: https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia (visited on 08/07/2020).//Merriam-Webster (2020). Abulia. In: Merriam-Webster.com dictionary. url: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia (visited on 08/07/2020).]

If you haven't used `biblatex` before, you may want to read [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) to see what you have to do to switch. Keep in mind that `biblatex`'s default backend is Biber and not BibTeX, so ideally you would compile your document with Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Here's what `natbib` makes from `@incollection`s

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{mw:abulia,
  author    = {Merriam-Webster},
  title     = {Abulia},
  booktitle = {Merriam-Webster.com dictionary},
  year      = {n.d.},
  url       = {https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia},
  note      = {Retrieved 8 Jul. 2020},
}
@incollection{oed:akrasia,
  title     = {akrasia, n.},
  booktitle = {OED Online},
  year      = {2020},
  month     = jun,
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  url       = {https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia},
  note      = {Retrieved 8 Jul. 2020},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citep{mw:abulia,oed:akrasia}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: akrasia, n. In OED Online. Oxford University Press, June 2020. URL https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240257?redirectedFrom=akrasia.Retrieved 8 Jul. 2020.//Merriam-Webster. Abulia. In Merriam-Webster.com dictionary. n.d. URL https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abulia. Retrieved 8 Jul. 2020.]